# Higher-order functions on Symfony2/3

Tags: symfony

Checking laravel documentation I found out this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods which looks like an awesome addition to use the so called higher-order functions, is there any way to have this also on symfony2/3? Any bundle or built-in alternative?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could try using the Laravel component, you gave as an example, in your Symfony project simply as a library. Try installing it via composer: https://github.com/illuminate/support and just use desired helper classes directly in your project. That might just work.

As an alternative, this library might be helpful for you too: https://github.com/Anahkiasen/underscore-php